# LED 12 V, 30 A power supply blinking and 0 V output

Tags: power-supply, power, led

I bought a 12 V, 30 A LED power supply for a chemistry experiment (electrolysis). The  power dropped to 0 and the onboard LED in the power supply started blinking when the anode and cathode were in the water and electrolyte.

I read about a similar situation, and the behaviour seems to be due to overcurrent; a protection function of some adapters.

How can I make this work like a regular adapter? Are there other methods to control this current issue?

[image: led power supply blinking]

[Short clip showing the blinking. Ignore the wire colors. I thought it was due to the wiring, but it wasn't.](https://youtube.com/shorts/H-aCFWqidmY)

[image: LED Power supply inside picture]

Comment: Your solution probably has a very low resistance, and the power supply is overloaded. Buy a laboratory power supply so you can control the current and voltage; and measure the current. A laboratory power supply can be put in constant current mode.

Comment: note: the stripped ends of the wires are too long ... the end of the insulation should be inside the screw compartment

Comment: you might be able to put some resistance in series to limit the current. Something like an automotive headlight bulb might do the trick. If you use a H4 bulb, you have the choice of two resistances - high beam or low beam. You get a visual feedback as to how much current is being drawn. Note - the bulb gets hot!

Comment: If it's a LED power supply, see if it has a constant current (CC) mode, and use that. Otherwise the filament auto headlamp of Kartman is an excellent idea.

Comment: Is lowering the electrolyte concentration  to increase the solution's resistance an option? If not, I'd go for Kartman's Light Bulb.

Comment: Off topic: Brave to use black and yellow-green as positive wires!

Comment: tnX guys for help 1. sadly anything above 5% electrolyte do this to power supply so practically make it un usable 2. lamp idea ok i will try that and update

Comment: H4 Bulbs worked thou both cables & lamp getting hot i guess need add fan or something along the way thank you for your help Kartman

Answer (score 3):

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>I found the PSU's schematic but I'm not going to share it here.</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

The converter is a TL494-based half-bridge converter having CV and CC control. This means that as long as the output current is below the pre-set value (around 40 A as I can see) the converter runs in CV mode and regulates the output voltage; but once the current exceeds the pre-set value the converter drops into constant current (i.e. regulates the output current) and loses voltage regulation, therefore output voltage drops.

In your case, if your experiment causes a significant current draw then the converter **should** limit the current and decrease the output voltage accordingly. As the load tries to draw more current the output voltage will drop more until the voltage drops below some threshold.

If the output voltage drops below that threshold the converter will assume that there's a short circuit so the short circuit protection will kick in. Different designs have different short circuit protection implementations such as periodic restarts (hiccup), latched stop, etc. Yours seems to have the first type: The converter forces itself to restart hoping to see the load within the specified range but triggers the short circuit protection. That's why you see a blinking LED indicator.

Comment: Thank you Rohak  seems thats the case so whats the solution for this? as you know electrolysis means very very low resistance in water can  perhaps adding PWM helps?

Comment: @AminMyCard PWM won't be solution because full current will flow for a non-zero time. You may try limiting current by adding resistance such as light bulb as others suggested above.

Comment: so in the end i have to add some sort of resistor to mimic real load for power supply can you help me out what ohm & wattage need for this, sorry about delay reply Internet is blocked in IRAN due protests

Comment: Well it's hard to tell because I don't know if your experiment requires voltage or current. If only the current is what you need then simply the resistance should be higher than or equal to 12V / 33.3A = 360 milliohms. But, as I said, I don't know what voltage and current you need.

Comment: finally i got my internet back, electrolysis need currents any voltage above 2.5V only heat up the solutions

Comment: @AminMyCard sorry I totally forgot about this question. So, although your experiment requires a voltage of at least 2.5V you should also limit the current as well. Because your experiment basically shorts the power supply (i.e. the current flow can be infinite) due to the liquid content, I personally recommend you to use an adjustable CV/CC PSU because the one you used has a pre-defined CC limit thus the output voltage drops significantly and affects your experiment. With adjustable CV/CC PSU you can play with output current so it's better for experiments.